# Error when installing Docker enterprise edition trial using mirantis launchpad

Tags: docker, installation, launchpad, ucp

I am getting the following error(panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference) when trying to install Docker Enterprise edition trial using Mirantis LaunchPad. I am pretty new to Docker EE, Appreciate any suggestions to resolve the issue.

Additional Details: Running Launchpad on Windows 10 pc
Destination : Azure CentOS8.1 VMS

[image: Config File]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kiran!  The problem is you need to register first.  To do that, just do:

```
launchpad register
```

and follow the prompts.  From there, you can use

```
launchpad apply
```

as usual.  Thanks!